# php generated image in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, gdlib

I have a picture generated with GDLib. 
In this picture gdlib adds some gif dots in various locations, according to database data.

Now i would like to somehow identify these dots with javascript and make a simple fadein/fadeout function for these dots.

However since its being done with gdlib, i assume the images is interpreted as being just 1 image, and therefore i cannot idetify these dots with JS.

So my question is which technique i should use for this ?

Thanks

Comment: simple solution: send 2 pictures - one with dots, one without. Combining javascript (clientside!) and php (server) -> cold shivers up'n down my spine. and yes, ajax....

Comment: I'd probably just draw everything with `canvas` instead. Edit: Or, like Bart suggests, "draw" everything with HTML elements (one wrapping `div` and a bunch of `spans` for the dots should do it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a picture of a dot and use absolute positioning to put it over the image.

Comment: Was hoping there was another solution, as i would have to create up to thousands of spans or divs, in order to make it work.
But seems this is the way to go. Thank you